Junit combined conditions with or/and between them
I have integration test setup written in Kotlin, that runs with junit (can't change that) and is environment dependent.
We can't use spring (which allows the expression language) either.
For example - I need the test to run if the region is AWS region 'us-west-1' and Account Y (both have to apply), or region 'eu-west-2'.
The test should not run on any other combination of reagion + account.
I also have disabled if cases with similar logic - run unless this combination happens or this other one.
@EnabledOnEnvironment does not accept this type of combined ifs.
I tried a custom condition where I test multiple conditions, and for enablement it's fine (though not elegant).
However, when I need to disable a test on multiple conditions that have 'or' between them, it's another story.
The main issue I encountered so far is how to let another developer annotate their test methods easily.
I want the logic of something like:
@DisableIf("[region=us-west-2 and account=123456789] or [region=eu-west-1]")
But I don't want to introduce any form of a new syntax.
The best I made it so far is:
    @DisabledEnvCondition(
        envConditions = [
            EnvCondition(name = "stage", values = ["stage1"]),
            EnvCondition(name = "region", values = ["us-west-1"]),
        ]
    )

But this only goes as far as all or none.
To achieve my goal, I'll have to add another layer which would end up being too complicated from the using developer point of view.
    @DisabledEnvCondition(
        envConditionsOr = [
            allOf = [
                EnvCondition(name = "account", values = ["123456789"]),
                EnvCondition(name = "region", values = ["us-west-1"]),
            ],
            allOf = [
                EnvCondition(name = "region", values = ["eu-west-2"]),
            ]
        ]
    )

And I'll have to also have envConditionsAnd and anyOf and this is like creating a whole new framework, which I don't want.
Any ideas?
The current solution we have is methods that combine all those, so we have 4 methods for the above condition:

function that checks if account is ...
function that checks if region is us-west-1
function that checks if region is us-west-2
function that checks if 1 & 2 are true or 3 is true.

And we repeat that for every sub-setup.
I tried using some combinations of the @EnabledIf and @DisabledIf` built-in into junit.
